# Compilation Error in Android Api sample applicaiton after import into eclipse

Tags: android

I have imported the android api sample applicaition into Eclipse. I am getting compile error in import and where ever this R is used. Api levels are fine, I couldnt see R.class is getting generated. Please spot my prob and help me out fix this.

```
`import com.example.android.apis.R;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clean the project(go to project->clean)...if not solved
manually add the library(right click project->properties-->search for 'java build path)

Comment: The jre system libray was not added in the project, once added the issue get resolved.. Thnax for ur answer..

Comment: @j1s make it as correct answer.because other people can find out and implement it.make your resource as best as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I finally debugged why this hasn't been building. (I had it running in older SDKs.)

After trying the various suggestions here to no avail, I found that the project is missing the accessibility_node_provider_instructions string resource from res/values/strings.xml. Plus it also needed the android-support-v4.jar library for PrintBitmap.java.

This is with Android 4.4.2 (API 19).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the package name in the manifest tag of AndroidManifest.xml is correct `com.example.android.apis`

If you have created the api samples project via. eclipse -> New ->Android Sample Project you should not have any project with package.

Comment: The jre system libray was not added in the project, once added the issue get resolved.. Thnax for ur answer..

Answer (score 0):

The jre system libray was not added in the project, once added the issue get resolved.